# Release nuget packages that have reference to other assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm writing an API, with some assemblies, I'd those assemblies to be published as nuget packages (it's actually done).

It's splitted over :

- ChickenAPI.Core (the "core" related things of an app, logger, IoC container, some maths Utils, abstracted Event pipeline...)
- ChickenAPI.Data (all the data acces layer, DTOs and abstracted "repository")
- ChickenAPI.Enums (all game enums)
- ChickenAPI.Game (all the game related things, game entities, components, events...)
- ChickenAPI.Packets (all the packet structures used by the game)

I'd like to release each one of those on nuget, but some are dependant to some others (example Game is dependant to Core, Data, Enums and Packets, Data is dependant to Enums...)

Should I link them with local reference or should I link each of their links to respective "remote packages"  ?
Here is the link of the related API : https://github.com/BlowaXD/ChickenAPI/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a nuspec file to do this - regular .NET Core SDK project files work fine.

Use `<ProjectReference>` to refer to one project from another, and that will be part of the dependencies in the NuGet package.

For example:

**ChickenApi.Core.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- TODO: Extra NuGet properties, e.g. Description, Authors -->
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**ChickenApi.Game.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- TODO: Extra NuGet properties, e.g. Description, Authors -->
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ChickenApi.Core\ChickenApi.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If you run `dotnet pack -c Release` on the solution, that will create two `nupkg` files, one for each project. Just publish both packages, and all will be well.

One thing to be aware of though is that if you change `ChickenApi.Core` and then depend on those changes in `ChickenApi.Game`, you *must* publish both packages (with updated version numbers). It's easy to forget to change the version of `ChickenApi.Core`, and publish a new version of `ChickenApi.Game` which *claims* it's still referring to 1.0, but depends on changes that aren't in the *published* 1.0.

Comment: Both are working, however your solution is quite easier to manage. (It was so obvious that I didn't even try it)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I've succeed to do it through Nuget's .nuspec files.

Here is the XML i'm using to build it

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ChickenAPI.Game.Extensions</id>
    <version>$(VERSION_OF_CHICKEN_API)</version>
    <authors>BlowaXD</authors>
    <projectUrl>http://github.com/BlowaXD/ChickenAPI</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BlowaXD/ChickenAPI/develop/docs/_media/logo_256.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>ChickenAPI.Game.Extensions is an collection of useful methods to manage game objects</description>
    <summary>ChickenAPI is an API for Nostale Private Servers</summary>
    <copyright>Copyright © BlowaXD 2019</copyright>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="ChickenAPI.Game" version="$(VERSION_OF_CHICKEN_API)" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

and here the command line I'm using to build the package :

```sh
dotnet pack -c Release src/ChickenAPI.Core --output nupkgs /p:NuspecFile=chickenapi.core.nuspec /p:NuspecBasePath=.
```

Thanks to that [declaring nuget packages that depend on each other in one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097335/declaring-nuget-packages-that-depend-on-each-other-in-one-solution) other question.

This pull request will show how I solved the issue (with every single details) : 
https://github.com/BlowaXD/ChickenAPI/pull/96